# Tibco Spotfire OVER function in an IF statement not working as expected

Tags: spotfire, tibco

Struggling to understand how an OVER function wrapped in an IF statement is operating.  Sample dataset and formulas provided below:

The "Count Over Test 3" column, is a simple OVER statement as below:

```
Count() OVER ([Product])
```

[image]

This I understand, on the "Fruit" product rows, it gives a value of 8 as there are 8 rows in the data with a product of Fruit, and for Veg there are 4 records etc.

The "Count Over Test 2" column has a calculation:

```
Count() OVER ([Region],[Product])
```

[image]

This I understand, it counts the records matching the region and product combination.  So for Fruit in the North, there are 4 records - for Veg in the North there are 2 records in the data set.

The "Count Over Test" column has a formula of:

```
If([Region]="North",Count() OVER ([Product]),Null)
```

What I expected this column to do is to:

- Only produce a value on the NORTH region rows because of the IF statement
- Give me the same value as "Count over Test 3" as it uses the same "Count() Over ([Product]) logic

Instead I get:

[image]

I thought that the OVER function, would operate over PRODUCT and give me 8 for Fruit again...the only impact of the IF statement being that the formula **is only calculated for the North rows**??  How can the IF statement control the partition of the OVER clause?

Comment: Sum it too. Its only going to display output for the North regions because of your IF.

Comment: I get that it will only display out for the NORTH, but the OVER I would have thought would operate over the entire data set.  I dont see how the IF statement adjusts the partitions the OVER statment operates over.

Answer (score 1):

I can agree that the IF statement functionality in this case is a bit odd.

What I would do is use two calculated columns.

```
Count() OVER ([Product]) as [HelperColumn]
```

and

```
If([Region]="North",[HelperColumn],Null)
```

[image]

In the example picture I didn't give the columns alias to show the expressions.